# Finding integral in Number Theory paper

Tags: integration, number-theory, indefinite-integrals

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\sin (\alpha t)}{t} \right)^2e^{i \nu t} \,\mathrm{d}t=\max(0,\alpha-|\nu|)$$

Apparently I found this in Montgomery's paper (1977). I need to know how exactly this happened. It looks strange when I am trying to do it by simple trigonometric expansion and integration by parts.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is simply the Fourier transform (inverse Fourier transform to be more precise) of
\begin{align}
f(t)^2 = \left(\frac{\sin \alpha t}{t} \right)^2
\end{align}
which is a product. Hence we see that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(f^2) = \mathcal{F}(f)\ast \mathcal{F}(f).
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform and $\ast$ denotes convolution of two functions. Moreover, the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is a characteristic function. I will let you finish this on your own.

Comment: I don't find it apparently true according to the inverse transform formula given in Wikipedia. Yes, Fourier Transform formula works, but, my bad, I'm not able to simplify it!